# Rails: Worker failing and increasing memory usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, sidekiq, algolia, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I've got a weird issue when using [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started) with [Algoliasearch](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails#with-sidekiq) in my Rails application.

Whenever I start sidekiq, it automatically performs all actions I configured with Algoliasearch:

```
# A post model

include AlgoliaSearch
algoliasearch if: :published?, enqueue: :trigger_sidekiq_worker do
    attributes :title, :subtitle, :content, :cached_votes_score, :cached_votes_total

    # the `searchableAttributes` (formerly known as attributesToIndex) setting defines the attributes
    # you want to search in: here `title`, `subtitle` & `description`.
    # You need to list them by order of importance. `description` is tagged as
    # `unordered` to avoid taking the position of a match into account in that attribute.
    searchableAttributes ['title', 'subtitle', 'unordered(content)']

    # the `customRanking` setting defines the ranking criteria use to compare two matching
    # records in case their text-relevance is equal. It should reflect your record popularity.
    customRanking ['desc(cached_votes_score)', 'desc(cached_votes_total)']
end

private

def self.trigger_sidekiq_worker(record, remove)
    ::Algolia::Blog::PostsWorker.perform_async(record.id, remove)
end
```

*Logs:*

```
$ bundle exec sidekiq


         m,
         `$b
    .ss,  $$:         .,d$
    `$$P,d$P'    .,md$P"'
     ,$$$$$bmmd$$$P^'
   .d$$$$$$$$$$P'
   $$^' `"^$$$'       ____  _     _      _    _
   $:     ,$$:       / ___|(_) __| | ___| | _(_) __ _
   `b     :$$        \___ \| |/ _` |/ _ \ |/ / |/ _` |
          $$:         ___) | | (_| |  __/   <| | (_| |
          $$         |____/|_|\__,_|\___|_|\_\_|\__, |
        .d$$                                       |_|

Signal TTIN not supported
Signal TSTP not supported
Signal USR1 not supported
Signal USR2 not supported
2017-04-25T18:50:30.134Z 5596 TID-c0loo INFO: Running in ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
2017-04-25T18:50:30.134Z 5596 TID-c0loo INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2017-04-25T18:50:30.135Z 5596 TID-c0loo INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
2017-04-25T18:50:30.136Z 5596 TID-c0loo INFO: Booting Sidekiq 5.0.0 with redis options {:url=>nil}
2017-04-25T18:50:30.138Z 5596 TID-c0loo INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2017-04-25T18:50:30.207Z 5596 TID-1nla70 Algolia::Blog::PostsWorker JID-262b2f8613a197637d05caf3 INFO: start
2017-04-25T18:50:30.539Z 5596 TID-1nla70 Algolia::Blog::PostsWorker JID-262b2f8613a197637d05caf3 INFO: fail: 0.333 sec
2017-04-25T18:50:30.540Z 5596 TID-1nla70 WARN: {"context":"Job raised exception","job":{"class":"Algolia::Blog::PostsWorker","args":[1,false],"retry":true,"queue":"default","jid":"262b2f8613a197637d05caf3","created_at":1493146072.768356,"enqueued_at":1493146072.768356,"error_message":"Couldn't find Blog::Post with 'id'=1","error_class":"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound","failed_at":1493146230.538659,"retry_count":0},"jobstr":"{\"class\":\"Algolia::Blog::PostsWorker\",\"args\":[1,false],\"retry\":true,\"queue\":\"default\",\"jid\":\"262b2f8613a197637d05caf3\",\"created_at\":1493146072.768356,\"enqueued_at\":1493146072.768356}"}
2017-04-25T18:50:30.541Z 5596 TID-1nla70 WARN: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Blog::Post with 'id'=1
```

I don't know if that behaviour is intended as algolia seems to just try to index a record with the id of 1. As far as I understand it, it should only index after a record got created, deleted or updated.
After the worker failed it starts over, so I accumulate a lot of memory. In some occasions, I also get a `LoadError` even though all my classes and namespaces are named correctly.

I don't know if the issue is with Algolia or Sidekiq.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that it has, in its queue, a job to index an object that doesn't exist anymore.

The queue should handle it correctly, and I'm not sure why it doesn't.

Could you try clearing your Sidekiq queue?
To clear all your queues, run:

```
Sidekiq::Queue.all.each &:clear
```

in a console, and then try again.

Comment: I've noticed that the [algoliasearch-rails](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails) gem (I am using it together with Sidekiq) tries to index records with an id of `1` whenever I start Sidekiq. I think that is causing the problem - I opened an issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails/issues/229)